# Patternmatching with variable part, which is the same in different filenames

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a lot of files in one directory named: `world_map_1.png`, `world_map_2.png`, `world_country_1.png`, `world_country_2.png`, ...

I want to use ImageMagick to append `world_map_2.png` to `world_map_1.png` and store the output in `world_map.png`. I want to do this for all files starting with `world` and ending with `1` and `2`, so my approach was:

```
convert world_*_1.png world_*_2.png +append world_*.png
```

The problem is that * must be the same in all 3 names, so I need a kind of variable for this, which I could reuse in the 2nd and 3rd name.

Comment: I added the tags to make it clear that you're on windows...

Comment: Is the variable part `map` always surrounded by `_`?

Comment: Concerning the input file yes, concerning the output file: no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a command to detect uniq "infixes":

```
for image in world_*_*.png
do 
    tmp="${image/world_/}"
    echo "${tmp/_*/}"
done | sort -u
```

Then, loop over them

```
for token in $(for a in world_*_*.png; do tmp="${a/world_/}"; echo "${tmp/_*/}"; done | sort -u)
do 
    convert "world_$token"_*.png +append "world_$token.png"
done
```

Creating some fake image files:

```
touch world_{map,country,something,else}_{01..04}.png
```

The command runs all of the following lines:

```
convert world_country_01.png world_country_02.png world_country_03.png world_country_04.png +append world_country.png
convert world_else_01.png world_else_02.png world_else_03.png world_else_04.png +append world_else.png
convert world_map_01.png world_map_02.png world_map_03.png world_map_04.png +append world_map.png
convert world_something_01.png world_something_02.png world_something_03.png world_something_04.png +append world_something.png
```

Comment: I guess this is for linux? Just tried it on a windows machine and got an error.. Seems like windows batch has problem with the for loop somehow: `"image" can not be worked syntactically at this place.`

Comment: Yeah. Somehow windows doesn't like POSIX shells. Best to change your question so other people don't waste time. (I totally use a bash shell on windows, but I guess that's off-topic)

Comment: Thanks for adding/changing the tags! I will try to port your solution to windows, shouldn't be too hard and if it troubles me too much I just do it in Linux with your script..

Comment: I doubt "it shouldn't be too hard". I mean, it's trivial if you can use bash (I do). Otherwise... don't bother porting. Just use PowerShell instead.

Comment: Ahh thanks a lot! Works like a charm with powershell! Didn't know that PowerShell also can run bash =)

Comment: Huh. Neither did I. That's weirdly surprising :)